# Rating for all images in a singular node?

Tags: 7, users, media

Setting up a private gallery for a photographer, so that their clients may log in, see images specific to a certain photoshoot, and check a box, or click a star to favorite different images. Any ideas of how I would set something like this up? An example of this currently being done would be Adobe's Lightroom.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look on FiveStar module : https://www.drupal.org/project/fivestar

Comment: Doesn't the FiveStar module require that each image be it's own individual node? Is there a way to apply the module across several images uploaded to a single node?